# Изменить язык программы

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Как изменить язык программы используя стандартные средства локализации.
Создал ресурс MyForm.ru-RU.resx для русификации, подскажите как правильно применить изменить язык используя данный ресурс ?

Comment: Winforms? WPF? Командная строка?

Comment: использую Winforms с++cli